# How do I include a row that is not in the table to the result set?

Tags: sql, sorting, oracle11g

Oracle 11g. WASHINGTON DC is not in my STATES table and I don't have authority to add it,  but it needs to be in the result set. I also want DC to appear first in the sort order.

```
STATES
STATE_ID  STATE_DESC
----------------------
 FL       FLORIDA
 HI       HAWAII
 WY       WYOMING
-----------------------------------------

select 'DC' state_id, 'WASHINGTON DC' state_desc from dual
union
select state_id, state_desc from states
order by 
case  state_id
when 'DC' then 'AAAA'
else state_desc
-------------------------
```

Above query yields following Error Msg:

```
 ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression
```

### Desired Result

```
 STATE_ID  STATE_DESC
 DC        WASHINGTON DC
 FL        FLORIDA
 HI        HAWAII
 WY        WYOMING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to just need an outer `SELECT` to apply the `ORDER BY` to.  Something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with states as (
  2    select 'FL' state_id, 'Florida' state_desc from dual union all
  3    select 'HI', 'Hawaii' from dual union all
  4    select 'WY', 'Wyoming' from dual
  5  )
  6  select state_id, state_desc
  7    from (select 'DC' state_id, 'Washington D.C.' state_desc
  8            from dual
  9          union all
 10          select state_id, state_desc
 11            from states)
 12   order by (case when state_id = 'DC'
 13                  then 'AAA'
 14                  else state_desc
 15*             end)
SQL> /

ST STATE_DESC
-- ---------------
DC Washington D.C.
FL Florida
HI Hawaii
WY Wyoming
```

While it probably doesn't matter much since your `STATES` table probably only has 50-ish rows, but doing a `UNION ALL` rather than a `UNION` will generally be more efficient since it doesn't require Oracle to check for and eliminate duplicate rows.

Comment: Justin, UNION ALL returns 39K rows whereas UNION returns my expected 50ish rows..

Comment: Obviously your actual table includes duplicates which you didn't mention in your actual question.

Comment: The Primary Key for my state table is the single column, state_id. States table has no duplicates.

Comment: @zundarz - Then how could the `UNION ALL` version of the query return 39,000 rows?  That means that you have 39000 rows in the `STATES` table but that there are only 50-ish rows when you remove the rows that have the same `state_id` and `state_desc` values.  That makes no sense if `state_id` is a primary key.  Is there more to your query that you haven't posted that is causing the number of rows to balloon?

Comment: @Justin: The query, I used to implement your solution included a join to a table that allows duplicate state_id. That's the source of the additional row counts. So the UNION ALL did not return 39K rows for the solution you posted here.

Comment: @zundarz - Are you sure that you really want to do the join, increasing the number of rows by ~1000, only to then filter out all the duplicates?  If you can end up with only 50 rows in the result, it sounds like you don't really want to join to the other table-- perhaps you just want an `IN` or an `EXISTS` that refers to the other table?

Comment: @Justin, I appreciate this questioning. After reviewing my query, the join is not really necessary as I can accomplish desired results without it. I used it because it had additional codes that weren't in the STATE table. Then I came across a code that was in neither table which prompted this OP. Given the solution you posted here, I'm not at the mercy of other tables at all. You've helped considerably.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Oracle to check the optimiser however I'd be inclined to adopt an approach such as this

```
SELECT  State_ID, State_Desc
FROM    (   SELECT 1 AS SortOrder, State_ID, State_Desc
            FROM States
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 0, 'DC', 'WASHINGTON DC' 
            FROM Dual
        ) 
ORDER BY SortOrder, State_ID
```

to alter the sort order, rather than using a case statement. Using the `SortOrder` column is definitely more efficient in SQL-Server-2008.